# How to handle large payload attacks?

Tags: java, web-services, soap

I have soap based large payload (bytes) data on webservice call. How do i ensure that application will be proof from:

- Malicious client generating fake requests with large payload keeping server busy handling fake requests?
- How to reject extremely large payload before encountering OME to protect server crash?

Comment: Is this service exposed over public network?

Comment: Yes, service is exposed over public network

Answer (score 0):

Unless you authenticate your clients either via SSL authentication or at least via login it is extremely difficult to distinguish valid and fake requests that could cause DoS. In the latter case hire a professional consultant. My 2 cents on this...